# How to link otf fonts together so they can be used together?

Tags: fonts, glyph, opentype, ligature

Ok, I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, but I'm not *entirely* sure I'm asking the right question here. I'm working on a custom font for a conlang (constructed languages, like Elvish or Klingon) and it's composed of a lot of ligatures. the website I was using had limits to the number of glyphs or ligatures that could be made per font, so I was originally planning to just merge them together in something like fontforge, but that isn't as.. straightforward as I had originally anticipated. ligatures are more complicated than Unicode characters. Some of the posts I found on the topic mentioned linking fonts together so you'd have a base font and others linked that software would "fallback" to. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516073/how-do-i-transfer-several-glyphs-at-once-from-one-font-file-otf-to-another) mentioned enabling it in your OS, but ideally, the id wants it to be where you could install the fonts on whatever and they just work. without having to manually set it up on each device. I get this isn't what fonts were designed for but I just want to be able;e to type all the characters I've made.

Comment: I should add, I don't want to manually switch fonts for different characters because that would be especially painful for typing anything that uses ligatures from different fonts.

Comment: Don't add details in a comment, just update your post. As for merging fonts: why? If you're running into the limitations of some website, it's time to move to _real_ font tooling: grab a copy of [fontforge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/) and get crackin, and rely on places like https://typedrawers.com to help you master font building, this is a fairly specialised topic, with its own communities =)

Comment: Ditto to what Pomax said. And forget about font linking and fallback: put all the glyphs in a single font and add a GSUB table to handle ligature substitutions.